# Loop over range of numbers for distribution in R

Tags: r

Sorry if this is a really basic question, but I just couldn't figure it out on my own.

I'm currently learning R for college and I'm trying to figure out how to loop over a range of numbers and input them into a distribution function, like so:

```
for (i in 0:3) {
  dpois(i,2/3)
}
```

All I'm trying to accomplish here is for R to calculate a Poisson distribution for 0-3, with a lambda of 2/3.

R expects some additional input which I haven't quite figured out.
If I replace `dpois` with some other function (like `print()`), the loop works.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is already vectorized, and as such no `for`-loop is necessary.

`dpois(0:3, 2/3)` should do the trick.

Comment: Apart from providing a vectorized solution, it's better to tell the OP how to make the for-loop work.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, vectorization is not something that most people who come from e.g. Python are familiar with. There are multiple advantages to vectorization over for-loops.

Comment: I know the advantages of vectorization. But obviously the OP is new to R and he is even unfamiliar to for-loop in R. So apart from providing a vectorized solution, I think you should explain ***why the OP's code does not work and how to fix it***. Otherwise, the OP will never know how a for-loop work in R. (This's just a suggestion for completeness of this answer)